# How to add CSS to an eclipse HTML file

Tags: java, html, css, eclipse

My assignment is to create a class in java and add tags through comments to make it look just like this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/. My problem is though that the CSS doesn't stay with the html file. It comes out without the CSS. I've tried doing

```
<style>href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/stylesheet.css"</style>
```

but I can't get the CSS to stick. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you link css files in html

```
<link href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Even this isn't working. is there something specific I'm suppose to insert this?

Comment: Maybe your link is wrong. But this is the right way linking css files

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the lines as ususer2812693 mentioned. Just check whether, the css is file loaded into the browser using firebug. And also the css classes and ID s are correct  with html elements' classes and ID s. Or else, first try to download the css file which you refer and, try to call it locally from your html page.